# Populating matrix radio buttons from db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a project where people can give theire feedback about the website, just like www.usabilla.com. But i'm stuck at designing my database.

I would like to make it possible for users to create matrix radio buttons with a label above them. Something like the second image on this page; https://www.webpoll.org/program/help/Help_QuestionType_GRB.php

Does anyone of you guys have an idea how I should design my tables, including the relationship, to make this happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @maazza May i ask what part you edited?

Comment: only your i => I nothing much do not worry :) you can click on the time of the edit to see the changes

Answer (score 0):

You can create a standard Product table with id, title, description, etc...
and another table called product_ratings with a product_id relationship, user_id (User relation) and 4 more columns as Quality, Efficiency, Price, etc... every of this columns will be an integer or NULL.